# For em um ArrayList de Objetos em Java

Tags: java, exceção, objetos

Estou estudando Java e estou com um problema em um código que escrevi. 
Preciso ler o nome e a idade de 3 pessoas e dizer o nome da mais nova e o nome da mais velha. 
Sei que o melhor jeito para um número grande de pessoas seria usar dois laços para ordenação, mas fiz apenas umas validações simples com `if/else` só para completar o exercício, porém, meu erro esta acontecendo no laço que criei para ler 3 nome e 3 idades do teclado. 
O código dá um `InputMismatchException` sempre na segunda volta.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Exercicio2 {

    static class Pessoa{
        String nome;
        int idade;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        public void setNome(){
            System.out.println("Insira o nome:");
            nome = input.next();
            input.nextLine();

        }

        public void setIdade(){
            System.out.println("Insira a idade:");
            idade = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
        }
        }

    static public void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Pessoa> pessoa = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();
        Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
        Pessoa aux = new Pessoa();
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for(i = 0; i< 3; i++){
            p.setNome();
            p.setIdade();
            pessoa.add(i,p);
            System.out.println( pessoa.toString() );
            System.out.println( pessoa.size() );
        }

        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                if(pessoa.get(i).idade > pessoa.get(j).idade){
                    aux.idade = pessoa.get(i).idade;
                    pessoa.get(i).idade = pessoa.get(j).idade;
                    pessoa.get(j).idade = aux.idade;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(pessoa.get(i).nome + " é a pessoa mais nova e " +     pessoa.get(j).nome + " é a mais velha.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Cade o método `Pessoa.getNome()` ?

Comment: Editei o código e agora tô recebendo um IndexOutOfBoundsException. Acima, coloquei a minha edição.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, é o seguinte. Eu fiz aqui rapidão porque estou um pouco agarrado. Mas se entendi bem o seu problema, o que você precisa está nesse código aqui. Pode ser que você encontre algum erro de sintaxe, é porque não prático desenvolvimento todos os dias, principalmente em Java.

Mas espero que ajude, abraço!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Exercicio2 {

  static class Pessoa{

    private String nome;
    private int idade;
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void setNome(){

        System.out.println("Insira o nome:");
        nome = input.nex();
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void setIdade(){
        System.out.println("Insira a idade:");
        idade = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
    }

    public String getNome()
    {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public int getIdade();
    {
        return this.idade;
    }

    }

static public void main(String[] args){

    ArrayList<Pessoa> pessoa = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();

    Pessoa p;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for(i = 0; i< 3; i++){

        p=new Pessoa();
        p.setNome();
        p.setIdade();
        pessoa.add(p);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        for(j = 1; j <= 3; j++){

            if(pessoa[i].getIdade()>pessoa[j].getIdade())
            {
                Pessoa aux;
                aux=pessoa[i];
                Pessoa[i]=pessoa[j];
                pessoa[j]=aux;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(pessoa[0].getNome() +" é a pessoa mais nova e "pessoa[2].getNome()+ "é a pessoa mais velha.")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade a exceção lançada é uma [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) quando você tenta acessar os índices com o valor das variáveis `i` e `j` na antepenúltima linha:

```
System.out.println(
    pessoa.get(i).nome + " é a pessoa mais nova e " +
    pessoa.get(j).nome + " é a mais velha."
);
```

Ambas as variáveis possuem valor 3. E isso acontece nesse ponto:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
   }
   // saiu do loop porque j = 3
}
// saiu do loop porque i = 3
```

Seu `ArrayList` possui 3 pessoas, mas o índice no array vai de 0 a 2 `[0|1|2]`. Quando tenta acessar o índice 3 que não existe, <s>o caos cai sobre a Terra</s> é lançada a exceção.

Para resolver, você pode simplesmente subtrair 1 do valor contido em `i` e `j`. Ex:

```
System.out.println(
     pessoa.get(i - 1).nome + " é a pessoa mais nova e " +
     pessoa.get(j - 1).nome + " é a mais velha."
);
```

E pronto, sua `IndexOutOfBoundsException` está resolvida.

No entanto você ainda possui um problema de lógica no programa, nos testes que fiz sempre é retornado a última pessoa inserida, tanto para a maior idade quanto para a menor. Como não entendi o que você tentou fazer naquele *loop* segue uma outra forma de resolver:

<sub><sub>Tentei dar nomes que descrevam as variáveis, para evitar lotar o código de comentários.</sub></sub>

```
import java.util.*;

public class Exercicio2 {

    private static final int PESSOAS = 3;
    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Pessoa> listaDePessoas = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < PESSOAS; i++){
            Pessoa novaPessoa = new Pessoa();

            System.out.println("Nome: ");
                novaPessoa.setNome(input.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Idade: ");
                novaPessoa.setIdade(input.nextInt());
            input.nextLine();
            listaDePessoas.add(novaPessoa);
        }

        Pessoa maisNova, maisVelha;
        maisNova = maisVelha = listaDePessoas.get(0);

        for(Pessoa pessoa:listaDePessoas){
            if(pessoa.getIdade() > maisVelha.getIdade())
                maisVelha = pessoa;
            else if(pessoa.getIdade() < maisNova.getIdade())
                maisNova = pessoa;
        }

        System.out.printf("Mais nova: %s - %d", maisNova.getNome(), maisNova.getIdade());
        System.out.printf("Mais velha: %s - %d", maisVelha.getNome(), maisVelha.getIdade());         
    }

    static class Pessoa {
        int idade;
        String nome;

        public void setIdade(int idade) {
            this.idade = idade;
        }

        public void setNome(String nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
        }

        public int getIdade(){ return idade; }
        public String getNome(){ return nome; }
    }
}
```

Sobre problema da [`InputMismatchException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) (que não é o verdadeiro motivo do código funcionar incorretamente): Essa é uma exceção lançada quando o valor de entrada não coincide com o tipo esperado ou não está no intervalo do tipo esperado. No momento de inserir os dados pode ter ocorrido uma confusão e você inverteu a ordem de entrada, por exemplo, o seu método `nextInt` esperava receber um número referente a idade e acabou recebendo uma `String` contendo o nome da pessoa.

Não tenho conhecimento se um objeto `Scanner` pode guardar lixo de uma leitura anterior, mas também é algo a ser verificado.